# Windows 10 UAP back button

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10

How would I handle the back button for windows mobile 10 and the back button for windows 10 tablet mode? I've been looking everywhere but can't find any examples for it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This topic is one of the examples used in the [Guide to Universal Windows Platform apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn894631.aspx) . I strongly suggest reading that when getting started with Universal apps.

For the button on the page header use Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager and set the AppViewBackButtonVisibility property to show or hide the button and handle the BackRequested event to perform the navigation.

```
Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s,a) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("BackRequested");
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        a.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

You wire up the hardware back button the same as you do in Windows Phone 8.1, but you should check for the PhoneContract (or the individual class and method) to make sure it is there:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent ("Windows.Phone.PhoneContract", 1, 0)) {  
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += (s, a) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BackPressed");
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            a.Handled = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Where is AppViewBackButtonVisibility supposed to be put? MainPage contstructor doesn't do anything for me nor the OnLaunched in App.xaml.cs

Comment: It goes on the title bar automatically :)

Comment: Is there any way to customize the background color of the back button?

Comment: Maybe its better to check "ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))" because not every Phone get HardwareButtons like Lumia 630 etc.

Comment: Checking for the contract or for the type are equivalent here: if the contract is present then the class must be. The soft back button on the Lumia 630 still comes through the HardwareButtons class.

Comment: I could only thay that MS in his sampels:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

use "Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons". Maybe its better if there will be a Tablet with HardwareButtons or somthing else.

Comment: You're over thinking it. As I said in my answer, both ways will work here.

Comment: it works in my case, just wonder if it is possible manually dispatch back event?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following code to your App.xaml.cs and it will handle the navigation on desktop, tablet and mobile (I tested it on the mobile emulator)
for better highlighted differences and explanation ([Handling The Back Button In Windows 10 UWP Apps](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps) by [JEFF PROSISE](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/author/jprosise))

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
            rootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            // Register a handler for BackRequested events and set the
            // visibility of the Back button
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                rootFrame.CanGoBack  ?
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }

    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }

    private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Each time a navigation event occurs, update the Back button's visibility
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
            ((Frame)sender).CanGoBack ?
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this on my Lumia 950 to hide the buttons along the button, back, home and search.  It doesn't do anything and they are still there, any ideas why?

Comment: The answer is in regard to the special back button that appears on the top left and handling the hardware button that has a default behavior of exiting the app. it doesn't have anything to do with home and search buttons.

Comment: aah okay thanks, my bad.  I found the info I wanted in the end.

Comment: i have an error, like a this picture: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7Q0yE5XjtLC-RX8A. How to handle it?