# Back button for Windows 10 hosted app

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows, windows-10

I am making a Windows 10 hosted Webb app following [this](http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm). Now when the user press the back button on the phone, it seems that it just quit the app. I want the app just go back to the previous page.How can I do that? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597585/windows-10-uap-back-button) but this is for C#. How about the case for Web App? Thanks!

Comment: use `SystemNavigationManager` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigationn-windows-10-uwp/35875842#35875842

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 10 UWP apps are being shipped without any templates, there is a GitHub project which contains many code examples to add to your Windows 10 application. Here's the project which implements a back button and multiple navigation features utilizing controls. It works on both Windows 10 Mobile and Desktop.

Link to project which implements SplitView (Back button and hamburger):

[https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A818A6F7EAABB150!451776&authkey=!ABr-Lk3FsiRAelY&ithint=file%2czip](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A818A6F7EAABB150!451776&authkey=!ABr-Lk3FsiRAelY&ithint=file%2Czip)

Link to original project (Didn't compile in VS 2015, so I fixed it in the app linked above)

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/201505-MVA/tree/master/SplitView/SplitView/SplitView-Template10

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the bak button the the phone. When user click on the back button on the phone now, it would just quit the app, but not go back to the previous page of the app.