# Handling Back Navigation Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

In my Xaml Page I've got a Frame.

I'm trying to have a backButton event to just navigate inside frame .

so I tried  to use this piece of code

```
public MainPage(){
    this.InitializeComponent();
    if(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons")) {
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }
}
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender,BackPressedEventArgs e) {
    if(insideFrame.CanGoBack())insideFrame.GoBack();
    else  Application.Current.Exit();
}
```

but In phone after doing `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` event it close the application.

It seems to running some default back button behavior on MainPage...

How can I fix it? And In Windows10 does they add new events to handle back navigation?

---

[Update]

Now I found out it's better to Use `SystemNavigationManager` in Windows 10 instead of `Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed`.

```
SystemNavigationManager currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
```

Comment: Use of `SystemNavigationManager` can be found in the following blog: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps

Comment: @Shahriar Will this work for Windows 10 Mobile also. Because I checked, back button is not displayed in Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the system that you handled the backbutton press by setting the Handled property of the BackPressedEventArgs to true.

```
  private void OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
  {
        // This is the missing line!
        e.Handled = true;

        // Close the App if you are on the startpage
        if (mMainFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(Startpage))
            App.Current.Exit();

        // Navigate back
        if (mMainFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            mMainFrame.GoBack();
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 24):

Windows 10 (UWP) include [SystemNavigationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager) in `Windows.UI.Core` namespace for Navigation purpose only.

Because `SystemNavigationManager` is part of `Windows Universal Platform`, So, it's supported by all device family running on Windows 10 including Mobile and PC.

## For Single Page

---

If you just want to handle navigation for single page. Follow the following steps

**Step 1**. Use namespace `Windows.UI.Core`

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
```

**Step 2.** Register back request event for current view. Best place for this is main constructor of class after `InitializeComponent()`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //register back request event for current view
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += MainPage_BackRequested;
}
```

**Step 3.** Handle BackRequested event

```
private void Food_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

## For Complete Application at one place for single `rootFrame`

---

Best place for handling all backbutton for all Views is `App.xaml.cs`

**Step 1**. Use namespace `Windows.UI.Core`

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
```

**Step 2.** Register back request event for current view. Best place for this is `OnLaunched` just before `Window.Current.Activate`

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

**Step 3.** Handle BackRequested event

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        rootFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

---

References- [Handle back button pressed in UWP](http://www.developerinsider.in/2016/03/13/handle-back-button-pressed-in-uwp/)

Hope this is helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

**follow these steps:**

- Add two Global Variables in your page as below.

  ```
  private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
  private RelayCommand _GoBackCommand;
  ```
- Then add below code in constructor of specific page.

  ```
      // below code is to override the back navigation
      // hardware back button press event from navigationHelper
      _GoBackCommand = new RelayCommand
          (
              () => this.CheckGoBack(),
              () => this.CanCheckGoBack()
          );

      navigationHelper.GoBackCommand = _GoBackCommand;
      // ---------
  ```
- Then add both those methods we've just declared in constructor.

  ```
  private bool CanCheckGoBack()
  {
      // this should be always true to make sure the app handles back buton manually.
      return true;
  }

  private void CheckGoBack()
  {
      // this will be execute when back button will be pressed
  }
  ```

ps. - for this you might need to use `BasicPage` instead of `BlankPage` while adding new page.

hope this will help..!

Comment: Where is `NavigationHelper ` ? As you know in Windows10 there is no template such windows phone 8.1 to have `NavigationHelper` inside it...
If you know... where can I get `NavigationHelper `?

Comment: In windows 10 there is no `BasicPage` ... it's just `BlackPage`

Comment: you can get the file from any existing wp8.1 project or may be from other project template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It will work for frame back navigation.

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

      HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

    }


    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {

    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because you add HardwareButtons_BackPressed in your page instead on in app.xaml.cs.

In app.xaml.cs :

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;

    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

Now, back button of your phone will work on any pages.

And then, if you want to add a particular button doing back in any page :

In the particular page (or each pages if you want) :

```
public void btn_return_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

Source :
http://windowsapptutorials.com/tips/general-tips/handling-the-back-button-in-a-windows-phone-8-1-app/

Comment: insideFrame is not in App.xaml.cs scope

Comment: Thanks for the tips cosmo0. Edited my answer to fix this.