# how to cancel navigate back on back button pressed in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-rt, windows-10-mobile

How can I cancel current page to navigate back when back button pressed in Windows 10 UWP?

In windows Phone 8 or 8.1 Silverlight I can write this code and handle it

```
private void PageBackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
    if (MGMethods.DisplayMessageWithButton(MessageText))
    {
       //Can Navigate Back
    }
    else
    {
      //Stop to Navigate back
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
 }
```

But , in windows 10 How can I do this same logic.

I have tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Back Navigation Windows 10 (UWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigation-windows-10-uwp)

Answer (score 2):

The `SystemNavigationManager` lets you respond to user presses of the system provided back button such as a hardware button. To enable your app to respond to the system back-navigation event, call `GetForCurrentView` to get the `SystemNavigationManager` object associated with the current view, then register an event handler for the `BackRequested` event. Your app will receive the event only of it's the foreground app. If you handle the `BackRequested` event, set the `BackRequestedEventArgs.Handled` property to true to mark the event as handled. If you don't mark the event as handled, the system decides whether to navigate away from the app (on the Mobile device family) or ignore the event (on the Desktop device family):

```
Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s,a) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("BackRequested");
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        a.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[Source: MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

For hardware Back button you can use `BackPressed` event:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
             e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Or clear the Stack if other stack items not important:

```
this.Frame.BackStack.Clear();
```

Or:

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
frame.BackStack.Clear();
```