# windows universal app hardware backButton

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, back-button

I am creating a Windows universal app and I would like to implement some behavior for the (hardware)back button. I am able to do so for windows Phone using 
'using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;' 
and 
'HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;'

But can't seem to do it with the universal app, This behavior will happen on a page that is shared. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigationn-windows-10-uwp

Comment: yes, i can't use 'Windows.Phone'... that can only be used on the phone part of the universal app, and i want to get the press event on a shared page(for both windows and windowsPhone)...

Comment: `SystemNavigationManager` is what you want. It also works on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SystemNavigationManager`

```
SystemNavigationManager currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
```

And have an event handler like this one:

```
currentView.BackRequested += CurrentView_BackRequested;

private void CurrentView_BackRequested(object sender,BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
    if(Frame.CanGoBack)
      try { Frame.GoBack(); }
      catch(Exception) { }
}
```

And to Visible Back Button at corner of ur app (Desktop mode) :

```
currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

Comment: You need to set `Handled` to true if you successfully go back.