# Handling back button on different pages

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, back-button, windows-10-mobile

I have 2 page, MainPage and SettingsPage. In the MainPage there is a button that when clicked it allows to get to the SettingsPage using this code:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
```

Now I want that on the second page when the user clicks the back button the application go back to the MainPage.

I've tried by adding the following code:

```
public SettingsPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SettingsPage_BackRequested;
}

private void SettingsPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        this.Frame.GoBack();
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The application go back to the MainPage but the SettingsPage_BackRequested event continues to work so if I click the back button on the MainPage the app doesn't close.

How can i handle the backbutton in my application?

Comment: The root issue in this case is **always** setting `Handled = true` even when you do nothing. danyv's answer has a better all-up solution though.

Comment: use `SystemNavigationManager` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigationn-windows-10-uwp/35875842#35875842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you move your navigation code to the App object. The great news with the [SystemNavigationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager) is that you can centralize your code and make the default navigation process very easy to do.
Here's a simplified version

```cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    rootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    ...
}

private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        ((Frame)sender).CanGoBack ?
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

For more details, check this great tutorial

http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps