# GoBack() to previous page UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I launch a page on UWP thanks to PageRenderer, this page allows take picture and I want go back when user take a pciture.

My problem is when I go back with hardware button I have no problem but with function goback doesn't work.

This is my code :

```
 var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (frame != null && frame.CanGoBack)
                {
                    frame.GoBack();
                }
```

CanGoBack return false.

So you have **some idea**

Thanks

Comment: Try to subscribe to *SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested* event.

Comment: This function is for hardware button and my problème is on a classic button. But I try and I can't beacause cangoback() return false : 
 var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

                Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, a) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("BackRequested");
                    if (frame.CanGoBack)
                    {
                        frame.GoBack();
                        a.Handled = true;
                    }
                };
I think my problem is on my frame instance

Comment: What do you have in *Window.Current.Content*? Frame/Page? Have you debuged your code? When is your code fired? (there are some cases when the frame cannot go back)

Comment: I use Xamarin and a pageRenderer, so Window.Current.Content allow me to get my current frame (if i say it's a page I have this exception : System.AccessViolationException) 
Yes debug my code and my problem is on goback()
If I can't go back how I can close my frame ? I think it's possible because hardware button work.

Comment: A suggestion, New CameraCaptureUI https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui is available which works fine with going back and storing data with Xamarin.

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin but see [c# - Handling Back Navigation Windows 10 (UWP) - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigation-windows-10-uwp). Perhaps this is actually a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the back button pressed and then force the navigation back

```
        public PageContainer()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += PageContainer_BackRequested;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles when the user presses the back button 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void PageContainer_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
             Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
             if (rootFrame == null){
                return;
             }

            // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
            // already been handled .
            if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

This example is an adaptation of the [example provided on the MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx)

Comment: I apply your code in my page and I have the same problem, rootFrame.canGoBack return false and e.Hanlde == true.

Comment: Well that's the microsoft example soooo I don't know what to tell you without seeing more than 3 lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the BackPressed Event.

```
public Test()
{
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

private void Test_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
      if (this.Layer.CanGoBack) 
      { 
          e.Handled = true; 
          this.Layer.GoBack(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: What is Layer ?
My problem is not on Hardware button but on classic button.

Comment: I´m sorry. That was directly from my source code.

Layer is a Frame. In this case: This.Frame.GoBack();