# TitleBar back button for UWP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, win-universal-app, titlebar

I've seen that the windows settings are using a [back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86ae.png) in the title bar; and would like to include something like that in my UAP but since Win10 is pretty new I couldn't find any information if this is achievable in a simple way.

Thanks very much

Comment: similar question answered with some useful information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597585/windows-10-uap-back-button?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: use `SystemNavigationManager` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigationn-windows-10-uwp/35875842#35875842

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can activate the back button easily like this:

```
using Windows.UI.Core;

var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

Please note, that the back event is handled with the `BackRequested` event on the same view:

```
currentView.BackRequested += // Event handler goes here
```

Please note: The back button is only displayed in the title bar, when the app is running in desktop mode. When the app is running in tablet mode, the back button is moved to the Windows task bar (bottom left).

Comment: If you want to handle it everywhere in your project. Use it in your App.xaml.cs as shown [here](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps)

Comment: implement back button for all pages check this link => https://developerinsider.co/handle-back-button-pressed-in-uwp/

Answer (score 10):

Although the suggested answer still works as of Win10 1803, with the release of 1709 Microsoft began discouraging the use of AppViewBackButton in favor of an in-app back button. Here's some XAML:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"/>
```

Read more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation

Comment: Thank you - had overrided this and was driving my nuts and could not remember "NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle"