# How to control windows phone 10 hardware back button

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am developing WP10 application and I am navigating through pages in my app. However, the default back button is not working as it is working with windows phone 8 and windows phone 8.1

When I click the default back button the application is closed. What I want is that it should navigate to page where navigation occurred.

I used below, it works in windows 10 but it doesn't work in mobile version.

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += Settings_BackRequested;

private void Settings_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
       Frame.GoBack();
}
```

How I can handle the hardware back button in windows phone 10?
Thanks!

Comment: See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30607742/4574

Comment: Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832309/handling-back-navigationn-windows-10-uwp/35875842#35875842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with [Handling Back button in Windows 10 UWP](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps/)

Comment: It looks down for me. Could you provide an actual answer?

Comment: By default there is no home back button in windows 10, In order to control home back button, I followed that link and it solved the problem.